# k2 loop through all the rows in List View and pass data to another view

Tags: sharepoint-2013, k2

we have requirement to loop through the rows in List View, and then based on some condition we need to  pass the data to another view

```
if(impact=yes)
{

//increment a variable 
}
```

pass the variable to another view and set as the control value

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can use "For Each Looping" condition on a ListView and then create a condition based on the columns (or in K2 terminology SmartObject properties)
[image]